# Radius of convergence of a series which shows convergence for x>-a.

Tags: power-series

We need to find the radius of convergence of  $\sum_{i=1}^n a_n$ where
$a_n$=$(-4)^n*(x+2)^(2n)$/$n(n+1)$ .
By ratio test the series converges for |x+2|<1/4 i.e.
-9/4<x<-7/4 then what would be the radius of convergence? I know that if series converges for x=a then radius of convergence is R=0 but is it 1/4 here?

Comment: Yes, that $1/4$ is the radius of convergence. A "radius" is the distance from the center to the edge (that's how it works for circles); so for an interval, the radius is just half the interval length.

Comment: Yeah Thank you!Greg Martin

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Hadamard, the radius of convergence is: $r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{\sqrt[2n]{\dfrac{4^n}{n(n+1)}}}=\dfrac12$.